# finding/calculating closest objects on cartesian plane by distance PHP

Tags: php

So I'm trying to create a script in PHP that has multiple objects on a cartesian plane (xy) and to find the closest distance.

for e.g., lets say we have 3 objects on an XY plane and I want to find the 2 closest objects by distance.

Now I can use the distance formula:
http://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/distance_formula/index.php

However, how do I write a function on this that takes in an array of objects?

I'm thinking something like this (please advise):

-array $objects will be the list (of objects w/ names/coordinates)
-it should return array the closest object names

```
$object1 = ['object1' => 'a', 'x' => 1, 'y' => 1];
$object2 = ['object2' => 'b', 'x' => 1, 'y' => 3];
$object3 = ['object3' => 'c', 'x' => 5, 'y' => 5];
```

I'm not sure how to write this though. I've started the function:

```
function findClosestObject(array $objects) {

  d = sqrt(pow((x2-x1),2) + pow((y2-y1)),2))

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Put your objects in an array.
2. Iterate over the array.
3. You can save a fair number of CPU cycles by not performing the `sqrt()` since you don't care what the literal distance is.

eg:

```
function getDistanceIsh($a, $b) {
    return pow(abs(($a['x']-$b['x'])), 2) + pow(abs(($a['y']-$b['y'])), 2);
}

$testPoint = ['x'=>1, 'y'=>2];
$closest = $objects[0];
$closestDist = getDistance($testpoint, $objects[0]);

for( $i=1,$c=count($objects); $i<$c; $i++ ) {
    $dist = getDistance($testpoint, $objects[$i]);
    if( $dist < $closestDist ) {
        $closest = $objects[$i];
        $closestDist = $dist;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think @prim3 meant to find the closest two objects within a set of objects, not tested against a probe point. I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

For 3 objects, there are only 3 combinations of 2 objects - 1 + 2, 1 + 3, and 2 + 3.

Abstract your distance formula into a function :

```
function distance($obj1,$obj2) {
  return sqrt(pow(($obj1['x']-$obj2['x']),2) + pow(($obj1['y']-$obj2['y']),2));
}
```

Now calculate each combination of two objects, and store the results in an array :

```
$dist['12'] = distance($object1,$object2) ;
$dist['13'] = distance($object1,$object3) ;
$dist['23'] = distance($object2,$object3) ;

// sort values into ascending order
asort($dist);
// take 1st element index
reset($dist);
$closest = key($dist);

echo $closest;
```

To do this with a larger array of objects, you're going to need to implement code which first generates all the two-object combinations.

Comment: I had a brain thing that I'm going to dump here: For large numbers of points you could: 1. Create a spatial index. 2. Take the first to points and calculate the distance. 3. Query the index for points inside that radius and, if found, set the smaller radius, then continue for all other points. 4. Have `O(n*log(n))` or similar complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Writing your own code for such a computationally expensive programs is actually a bad start. Always first try to see if there is any Open Source code which can perform the same task more faster, and secure way. Because those codes are verified by many professionals and will mostly be error free, and also reduces your development time. So in your case, first finding the fastest algorithm is important. [Dijkstra Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) is widely used for finding the shortest path, and some examples of Open Source PHP code are [PHP-Dijkstra](https://github.com/DonVictor/PHP-Dijkstra) and [Taniko-Dijkstra](https://github.com/taniko/dijkstra)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that allows for a variable amount of objects (needs more than 1 of course). It utilizes [`hypot()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.hypot.php), which is basically the same as your distance formula.

```php
$objects = [
  [ 'name' => 'obj1', 'x' => 1,  'y' => 1 ],
  [ 'name' => 'obj2', 'x' => 1,  'y' => 3 ],
  [ 'name' => 'obj3', 'x' => 5,  'y' => 5 ],
  [ 'name' => 'obj4', 'x' => 10, 'y' => 8 ],
  [ 'name' => 'obj5', 'x' => 30, 'y' => 12 ],
  [ 'name' => 'obj6', 'x' => 31, 'y' => 13 ],
  [ 'name' => 'obj7', 'x' => 40, 'y' => 15 ]
];

function findClosestObjects( array $objects ) {
  // initialize $minDistance to null
  $minDistance = null;
  // total amount of objects
  $len = count( $objects );

  // loop from first object to the second-to-last
  // last will be handled inside nested for loop
  for( $i = 0; $i < $len - 1; $i++ ) {
    // set $o1 to current $i object
    $o1 = $objects[ $i ];
    // loop from next object to the last, to avoid duplicate pairs
    for( $j = $i + 1; $j < $len; $j++ ) {
      // set $o2 to current $j object
      $o2 = $objects[ $j ];
      // calc distance
      $distance = hypot( $o2[ 'x' ] - $o1[ 'x' ], $o2[ 'y' ] - $o1[ 'y' ] );
      // if $minDistance is null or $distance is smaller than $minDistance
      if( $minDistance == null || $minDistance > $distance ) {
        // put objects and distance in $result
        $result = [ $o1, $o2, 'distance' => $distance ];
        // and update $minDistance
        $minDistance = $distance;
      }
    }
  }

  return $result;
}

var_dump( findClosestObjects( $objects ) );
```

[<sup>view parsed online @ eval.in</sup>](https://eval.in/1039468)