# Get the axis distance with 3 given points php

Tags: php, math, formula, cartesian-coordinates

I want to know how to get a distance from three given points in the Cartesian plane using php. This is what I've done by far:

```
$p1 = (80, -35, 40);
$p2 = (38, 2.7, 1);
$p3 = (86, 5, 40);

public function getPoints($p1, $p2, $p3)
{
    $x = abs(($p2[1] - $p1[1]) + ($p2[2] - $p1[2]) + ($p2[3] - $p1[1]));
    $y = abs($x - $p2[2]);
    $z = abs($p3[3]);

    return ["x" => $x, "y" => $y, "z" => $z];
}
```

Thank you! UwU

Comment: Does this answer your question? [finding/calculating closest objects on cartesian plane by distance PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51431382/finding-calculating-closest-objects-on-cartesian-plane-by-distance-php)

Comment: That one seems to work only with a 2 dimensional space :(

Comment: What have you tried to resolve your problem?